# Identifying, reviewing, and deduplicating records in R

Tags: r

I'm looking to identify duplicate records in my data set based on multiple columns, review the records, and keep the ones with the most complete data in R. I would like to keep the row(s) associated with each name that have the maximum number of data points populated. In the case of date columns, I would also like to treat invalid dates as missing. My data looks like this:

```
df<-data.frame(Record=c(1,2,3,4,5),
           First=c("Ed","Sue","Ed","Sue","Ed"),
           Last=c("Bee","Cord","Bee","Cord","Bee"),
           Address=c(123,NA,NA,456,789),
           DOB=c("12/6/1995","0056/12/5",NA,"12/5/1956","10/4/1980"))

Record First Last Address DOB
1      Ed    Bee  123     12/6/1995
2      Sue   Cord         0056/12/5
3      Ed    Bee                     
4      Sue   Cord 456     12/5/1956 
5      Ed    Bee  789     10/4/1980
```

So in this case I would keep records 1, 4, and 5. There are approximately 85000 records and 130 variables, so if there is a way to do this systematically, I'd appreciate the help. Also, I'm a total R newbie (as if you couldn't tell), so any explanation is also appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain criteria for keeping records 1,4,5?

Comment: Sure. Records 1, 4, and 5 have the data for address included and the correct format for DOB (Date of Birth).

Comment: What is correct format for `DOB`?

Comment: I took the liberty of adding code to reproduce your example.

Comment: So basically, for each name, you want to keep the record that has the fewest missing data points?

Answer (score 0):

```
#Add a new column to the dataframe containing the number of NA values in each row.

df$nMissing <- apply(df,MARGIN=1,FUN=function(x) {return(length(x[which(is.na(x))]))})

#Using ave, find the indices of the rows for each name with min nMissing 
#value and use them to filter your data

deduped_df <-
df[which(df$nMissing==ave(df$nMissing,paste(df$First,df$Last),FUN=min)),]

#If you like, remove the nMissinig column
df$nMissing<-deduped_df$nMissing<-NULL


deduped_df
```

> ```
>  Record First Last Address       DOB
> 1      1    Ed  Bee     123 12/6/1995
> 4      4   Sue Cord     456 12/5/1956
> 5      5    Ed  Bee     789 10/4/1980
> ```

Edit: Per your comment, if you also want to filter on invalid DOBs, you can start by converting the column to date format, which will automatically treat invalid dates as NA (missing data).

```
df$DOB<-as.Date(df$DOB,format="%m/%d/%Y")
```

Comment: Thanks! In the first step that counts the number of NA values I ended up creating a column 'X' which just lists NA all the way down. I would think that is because I should have filled in a variable name in your code. Is that correct?

Comment: Also, in the second step, which worked well (Thanks!), I can only see the deduped data. How can I review the duplicate records?

Comment: And after the 3rd step of converting the DOB column to a date format, which seemed to work fine, I also tried to extract the age with the following code:"age <- floor(age_calc(dob = DOB, enddate = Sys.Date(), units = "years", precise = T))" **but** I got the following error: "Error in if (any(enddate < dob)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed" I've looked up what this error means and see that this is a "NA" error, but the date looks fine. Any ideas @AffableAmbler? Thank you for your help